# Connect Samsung Galaxy Heart Rate Monitor to fitness apps

Tags: fitness

With the fitness tracking revolution, I'd like to pair my heart rate to tracking apps. Is there a way to do this? It works with "S Health" but I want to EXPORT that data automatically or put it into another app.

For example, if I could upload my heart rate number into a Nike app, then use IFTTT to upload that to google spreadsheet, then use Zapier to connect it to beeminder, then I could be charged $5 if I don't work out that week, as PROVEN numerically by a heart rate sample from my android.

Or I guess I could just use gympact, but that doesn't user the heart rate monitor =/

Comment: http://forum.beeminder.com is a great place to ask this! Lots of similar Quantified Self nerdery discussed there.